# Navigation links pointing to custom views

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have an issue in dynamics crm 2011.

A campaign can have multiple campaign responses (1:n) relationship. 
I created several views for campaign responses depending on the value in an option set.

**How do I add links in the left side navigation of the Campaign screen that will open my custom filtered views of campaign responses ?**
I tried using this approach, modifying the customizations.xml from the exported solution, but it's not working.

http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2011/04/18/crm-2011-adding-a-view-to-the-sitemap/

My xml for the link is:

```xml
<NavBarItem Id="aaaa" Icon="$webresource:my_icon.png" Url="/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=campaignresponse&amp;viewid=%7bDCA90502-AF80-E111-8FC1-984BE11098B3%7d" Area="Sales" Sequence="1003">
   <Titles>
       <Title LCID="1033" Text="zzzzzzzzzzz" />
   </Titles>
</NavBarItem>
```

Note: My objective is to click the custom link from the left side navigation section of the campaign form and open the custom view for filtered campaign responses, of the current campaign.

If anyone succeeds in doing this, I would be grateful for an explanation and souce code used.

Comment: Side note: instead of using <NavBarItem>, did anyone manage to use <NavBarByRelationshipItem>, using a custom ViewId ? 
I couldn't make either of these work.

Comment: What is not working do you have a little more information about why it's not working?

Comment: Maybe try this link: http://crmdm.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-define-new-navigation-link.html

Comment: Ive never heard of being able to default a left nav item's view.  The associated view is the default one, and I didn't think changing the default was customizable.  The link that you displayed is not for associated views, but for the main window - where you can easily set up your own default view.